# Is this a insertionsort or bubble?

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort, insertion-sort

Is this a insertion or bubble? Because one of my professors failed me while the other one said it was correct...

```
protected void sort() {
            //Lite bättre när den redan är klar, slipper gå igenom hela
            for (int i = 1; i < getElementCount(); i++) {
                for (int j = i-1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    if (cmp(j+1, j) < 0) {
                        swap(j+1, j);
                    } else{
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Nothing in this code is inserting anything anywhere. These swaps make the bigger values "bubble up", hence it appears to be a bubblesort implementation. By the way: What did you tell those imaginary professors? Whats your own opinion on this?

Comment: Well...you're swapping elements on an `index + 1`, `index` basis...so which do you think based on the behavior of those respective algorithms?

Comment: that my friend looks like a bubble sort.

Comment: Since this is code, you can run it and see what it does.

Comment: Looks like a [gnome sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome_sort) to me: a derivative of insertion sort that repeatedly swaps a value until its insertion point instead of identifying the insertion point then rotating everything.

Comment: @Morwenn: It's the gnome sort with the "teleport" optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Because of that break, it's [Insertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)

Also it's almost duplicate of [Insertion sort vs Bubble Sort Algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270628/insertion-sort-vs-bubble-sort-algorithms)

Answer (score 0):

It is bubble sort algorithm. But I wonder your professors said it correct, what is "it" ?

Comment: No, that's not bubble sort.