# Python - Bubble sort

Tags: python, repeater, repeat, bubble-sort

Hi I reviewed other posts with bubble sort, but solution didn't work in my case:
So algorithm works until I repeat few times while loop. But how can I do this without using input? Here is my code so you know what I mean:

```
x = [0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5]

h = None
flag = True

while flag == True:
    #flag = True
    for i in range(len(x) - 1):
        if x[i] > x[i + 1]:
    #       flag = False
            h = x[i]
            x[i] = x[i + 1] 
            x[i + 1] = h
    print(x)        

    #input = raw_input('Satisfied? ')
    #if input == 'q':
    #   break

print(x)
'''
we can replace variable h, with:
x[i] , x[i+1] = x[i+1], x[i]
'''
```

Comment: You can iterate over your input list to check if there are any inversion or you can count the number of inversions in the current iteration, if they are 0 then you're done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the `sorted` function in python, and change your code to be:

```
while flag == True:
    for i in range(len(x) - 1):
        if x[i] > x[i + 1]:
            h = x[i]
            x[i] = x[i + 1] 
            x[i + 1] = h

    if sorted(x) == x: #x is already sorted
        flag = False
```

Edit: Alternate solution which doesn't use python's built in sort function:

```
while flag == True:
    flag = False
    for i in range(len(x) - 1):
        if x[i] > x[i + 1]:
            flag = True
            h = x[i]
            x[i] = x[i + 1] 
            x[i + 1] = h
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: Indeed, Thank You I learned something useful with cool trick sort(x) :)

Comment: It feels a little weird to use `sorted` within a function designed to sort things.

Answer (score 1):

With this algorithm, you can previously know how many steps (max) are needed to sort the whole array, because the algorithm is convergent and bounded. In each pass, the highest no-placed value is placed correctly, so you will need n-1 passes to complete the sorting.

Here an example:

```
mylist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]

for num in range(len(mylist)-1, 0, -1):
    for i in range(num):
        if mylist[i] > mylist[i+1]:
            aux = mylist[i]
            mylist[i] = mylist[i+1]
            mylist[i+1] = aux


print(mylist)
```

Hope it helps

PS: What you intended to do, stopping when the list is sorted before the n-1 pass, is better done with the "insertion algorithm". Here there is an interesting comparision between insertion and bubble sorting:
[Insertion sort vs Bubble Sort Algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270628/insertion-sort-vs-bubble-sort-algorithms)

Comment: That's interesting. Appreciate for sharing a link to Insertion. Thank You. I need more knowledge and I want to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I little refactor for your code:

```
for num in range(len(mylist)-1, 0, -1):
    for i in range(num):
        if mylist[i] > mylist[i+1]:
            mylist[i], mylist[i+1] = mylist[i+1], mylist[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python recursive bubble sort

```
def bubble_f(lst):
    if len(lst) < 2:
        return lst

    if lst[0] > lst[1]:
        return [lst[1]] + bubble_f([lst[0]] + lst[2:])

    return [lst[0]] + bubble_f([lst[1]] + lst[2:])

def bubble_sort(lst):
    if len(lst) < 2:
        return lst

    sorted = bubble_f(lst)

    return bubble_sort(sorted[:-1]) + [sorted[-1]]

list1 = [5, 9, 23, 4, 3, 8, 1, 12, 2, 9, 15, 19, 11, 27, 0]
print(bubble_sort(list1))
```