# Average case complexity analysis of insertion and bubble sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

This site already has some questions on this topic but I am confused after reading some of the answers.

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/20/evaluating-the-average-time-complexity-of-a-given-bubblesort-algorithm

In the above link, answer by "Joe" says that number of swaps in bubble sort on average is same as number of inversions on average which is (n)(n-1) / 4.

However, [Insertion sort vs Bubble Sort Algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270628/insertion-sort-vs-bubble-sort-algorithms) says that in bubble sort average number of swaps is n^2 /2 and in insertion sort it is n^2/4 and that's the reason for insertion sort being better than bubble sort.

Which one is correct? Can someone please help me?

Comment: How does each source define the average case? These comparisons might be apples to oranges. Best and worst cases are at least falsifiable. "Average" presupposes a distribution.

Comment: @Patrick87 What about the second link ? It says on average insertion sort beats bubble sort . Also the answer has lot of upvotes. Is it correct?

Comment: Both of these average number of swaps are within the same bounds of each other.  Is there some reason why you even need to use these two sorting methods over a divide-and-conquer approach like merge sort or quick sort?

Comment: The linked answer presumes an uniform distribution among all permutations of inputs. That might not be the case in practice, practice inputs are usually not uniformly distributed. Please explicitly specify the distribution you are interested in.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There is no reason as such. But the second link gives somewhat a stronger reason to go over insertion sort than bubble sort and somehow I don't fully agree with it.

Comment: @Zabuza what if we assume uniform distribution? Which one will be better ? I just want to know how to analyze average cases and how is insertion sort **really** better than bubble sort.

Comment: I don't fully agree with it either.  I just looked both algorithms up, and they are`O(n^2)` for both the average and worse case.  Not a motivation to use either of them really, but also not a reason to choose one over the other.  Unless you test on your actual data and, for some reason, one proves to really outperform the other.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Just out of curiosity, can you give an example where bubble sort outperforms insertion sort in terms of number of swaps? I can't think of one now.

Comment: @Zephyr The accepted answer in the second link doesn't appear to contemplate what the average case actually is. As such, any conclusion it reaches is suspect. Statements like "at most n, so on average n/2" are, in general, about as valid as "there are two possibilities, an asteroid destroying Earth this afternoon or not, therefore each must have probability 1/2". In the absence of any further information or thought, it's not a bad guess as guesses go, but it's not a very educated guess.

Comment: @Patrick87 Ok, if possible can you give an example or a case where bubble sort is actually better than insertion sort?

Comment: @Zephyr Actually, I can give you an example of where insertion sort outperforms bubble sort.  It happens to be the case where both algorithms would run in `O(n)` time.  Not sure if this is what you are looking for though.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah, even I was able to find a case where insertion sort beats bubble sort . But I am not able to find one where bubble sort is better than insertion sort. If the answer really depends on input data then there has to be atleast one case where bubble sort is better than insertion sort right ?

Comment: @Zephyr It looks like for the worst case scenario insertion sort also outperforms bubble sort.  I can't think of an obvious example here which meets your requirements.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ok, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your first link counts the expected number of inversions (i.e. swaps) assuming a uniform distribution.

Your second link is counting iterations i.e. inspections of elements.

Both are correct.