# Why does my bubblesort code need - 2 after the structure.Length for it to work?

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand why my productTable.Length has to be - 2 for my bubblesort code to work.

I created two int variables, Last_Position and i. I created one product variable called temp and one bool called swap which is set to false. I then set Last_Position to equal productTable.Length - 2.

This is where I fail to understand, from what I have read the .Length counts the amount of characters and returns the amount however since 1 counts as 0 in programming, you have to - 1 to have the cap be accurate (i.e 1000 = 999) which has remained true until this part.

For some reason - 1 will throw up an error when the program runs targeting this code: `if (String.Compare(productTable[i].prodCode, productTable[i + 1].prodCode) > 0)` and states "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'"

The code works when I set it to - 2 but I want to understand why that is.

```
    struct product
    {
        public string prodCode;
        public string description;
        public double price;
        public int quantity;
    }

    product[] productTable;

    public void loadData()
    {
        string path = "C:\\Users\\5004303\\Documents\\productFile.csv";
        int lineCount = File.ReadLines(path).Count();
        productTable = new product[lineCount];
        product currentProduct = new product();

        try
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);

            string line;
            int currentArrayLocation = 0;

            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                string[] fields = line.Split(',');
                currentProduct.prodCode = fields[0];
                currentProduct.description = fields[1];
                currentProduct.price = Convert.ToDouble(fields[2]);
                currentProduct.quantity = Convert.ToInt32(fields[3]);
                productTable[currentArrayLocation] = currentProduct;
                currentArrayLocation++;
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occured. Could not find file 'productFile.csv'.");
        }
    }

    public void listProducts()
    {
        int currentArrayLocation = 0;

        for (currentArrayLocation = 0; currentArrayLocation < productTable.Length; currentArrayLocation++)
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
            lvi.Text = productTable[currentArrayLocation].prodCode;
            lvi.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(productTable[currentArrayLocation].description));
            lvi.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(productTable[currentArrayLocation].price));
            lvi.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(productTable[currentArrayLocation].quantity));
            lvProducts.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
    }

    public void bubbleSort()
    {
        int last_Postion, i;
        product temp;
        last_Postion = productTable.Length - 2;
        Boolean swap = false;

        do
        {
            swap = false;
            for (i = 0; i <= last_Postion; i++)
            {
                if (String.Compare(productTable[i].prodCode, productTable[i + 1].prodCode) > 0)
                {
                    temp = productTable[i];
                    productTable[i] = productTable[i + 1];
                    productTable[i + 1] = temp;
                    swap = true;
                }
            }
        }
        while (swap == true);
    }
```

Comment: You've answered your own question: `productTable[i + 1].prodCode` - if you use `Length-1` you try to access the `Length` entry which is out of range, so you need `Length-2` to avoid this array access exception. (BTW, [insertion sort is better than bubble sort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17270628/1270789)...)

Comment: Thank you Ken, Eli made it more clear for me below so I understand your answer now, it is part of my access course which is why I am using bubblesort but I think we are looking at this sort as well in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
Change

`productTable.Lenght - 2` to `productTable.Lenght - 1`

and

`for (i = 0; i <= last_Postion; i++)` to `for (i = 0; i < last_Postion; i++)`

Explanation:

`productTable.Lenght` gives you the lenght of the list so `productTable.Lenght - 1` is the last position in the list (`0` to `productTable.Lenght - 1`).

In your "bubble" `for` loop inside the `while` you test against `i+1` so `i` should only go up to the `last_position - 1`.

In your code when `i == last_position` then `i + 1` is beyond the last position in the list.

Note: I did not check your code for validity, even if you make these changes, there may be other bugs.

Note on style, C# coding guidelines usually specify camel case for variable names, it is better to use `lastPosition` instead of `last_Position`. There are other styling "errors" in your code, such as declaring variables at the top of the function, using types instead of `var`. It may be some of this "errors" are course requirements, but a short read of any coding conventions document (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions) would be beneficial to you. Most work places have their own coding guidelines or adopt a public one, but on all of them are pretty similar.

Comment: Right I see so because I asked for it to be <= instead of < it counts the last position and goes through the loop again but when it reaches the loop again and goes through the if statement, the next value for [i + 1] does not exist and as a result crashes the program, giving me the error at the if statement line correct?

Yeah it is mostly course requirements and breaking it down for students to understand programming but I will give this document a look, thank you Eli.